# How to use external Javascript function in Angular 2 template?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a template in the component with 4 div tags. The JavaScript function I want to call, `changeValue()`, is supposed to change the content of the first div from `1` to `Yes!`. I'm new to TypeScript and Angular 2, so I'm not sure how I can get the template to interact with the function from `dtest2.js`:

```
 /**app.component.ts */

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <div id="boolean"><p id="bv">1</p></div>
  <div id="numeric"><p id="nv">2</p></div> 
  <div id="string"><p id="sv">3</p></div> 
  <div id="enum"><p id="ev">4</p></div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

```js
//dtest2.js

function changeValue(){
  var newVal= "Yes!"; 
  document.getElementById("bv").innerHTML= newVal;
}

changeValue();
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="file:^html/angular/app/bs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file:^html/dtest2.js"></script>
    
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there a special reason to use this `external js function`?
It would be better to use Angular's binding methods to solve your problem..

```
/**app.component.ts */

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

declare function changeValues(anyArgs: string, canBeHere: string) : void;

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <div id="boolean"><p id="bv">{{booleanValue ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</p></div>
  <div id="numeric"><p id="nv">2</p></div> 
  <div id="string"><p id="sv">3</p></div> 
  <div id="enum"><p id="ev">4</p></div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
    booleanValue: boolean = true;

    constructor() { changeValues(...); }

    anyFunctionToChangeTheValue() {
        this.booleanValue = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I edited the names of the divs. Ignore the boolean,string,etc. They are meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer said, you can do this natively in Angular 2. However, here is how you can access functions outside of Angular2. You just need to declare the "window" object as a constant in your Angular component.

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

const window: any = {};

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
  <div id="boolean"><p id="bv">1</p></div>
  <div id="numeric"><p id="nv">2</p></div> 
  <div id="string"><p id="sv">3</p></div> 
  <div id="enum"><p id="ev">4</p></div>
  `
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    changeValue();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is a [working example](https://embed.plnkr.co/oID2lQIeVbsRH2KeVp1C/).

Comment: I am getting a error in the terminal : File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
[0] app/app.component.ts(6,7): error TS1155: 'const' declarations must be initialized
[0] app/app.component.ts(20,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'changeValue'.

Comment: Yeah, this works in plnkr but it might not locally, let me see if I can create a working local example, I'lll update the answer when I have it.

Comment: I'm still getting the 'app/app.component.ts(20,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'changeValue' error. Is there something else perhaps wrong with my other files?

Comment: Try calling it with "window.changeValue()" instead of just changeValue()"

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
import { Component,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {};

ngAfterViewInit() {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "./app/custom.js";
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```